# Error: LaTeX failed to compile in RMarkdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, rstudio, pdflatex

I would like to use the template "APA-style manuscript (6th edition)" from the papaja package in RMarkdown to write papers/essays...

Windows 10
R-Version: 4.2.1
R-Studio: 2023.06.0 Build 421

This is the yaml code:

```
---
title             : "The title"
shorttitle        : "Title"

author: 
  - name          : "First Author"
    affiliation   : "1"
    corresponding : yes    # Define only one corresponding author
    address       : "Postal address"
    email         : "my@email.com"
    role: # Contributorship roles (e.g., CRediT, https://credit.niso.org/)
      - "Conceptualization"
      - "Writing - Original Draft Preparation"
      - "Writing - Review & Editing"
  - name          : "Ernst-August Doelle"
    affiliation   : "1,2"
    role:
      - "Writing - Review & Editing"
      - "Supervision"

affiliation:
  - id            : "1"
    institution   : "Wilhelm-Wundt-University"
  - id            : "2"
    institution   : "Konstanz Business School"

authornote: |
  Add complete departmental affiliations for each author here. Each new line herein must be indented, like this line.

  Enter author note here.

abstract: |
  One or two sentences providing a **basic introduction** to the field,  comprehensible to a scientist in any discipline.
  Two to three sentences of **more detailed background**, comprehensible  to scientists in related disciplines.
  One sentence clearly stating the **general problem** being addressed by  this particular study.
  One sentence summarizing the main result (with the words "**here we show**" or their equivalent).
  Two or three sentences explaining what the **main result** reveals in direct comparison to what was thought to be the case previously, or how the  main result adds to previous knowledge.
  One or two sentences to put the results into a more **general context**.
  Two or three sentences to provide a **broader perspective**, readily comprehensible to a scientist in any discipline.
  
  
keywords          : "keywords"
wordcount         : "X"

bibliography      : "r-references.bib"

floatsintext      : no
linenumbers       : yes
draft             : no
mask              : no

figurelist        : no
tablelist         : no
footnotelist      : no

classoption       : "man"
output            : papaja::apa6_pdf
---
```

However, I have problems with the knitting.
The problem ist LaTeX.

First, I tried MikTeX (I already had that on my computer, I also updated it before).
But it didn't work. I got the following error message in the render tab.

```
! Entschuldigung, aber C:\Users\JAKOBK~1\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe schlug fehl.

! Die Log-Datei enthält hoffentlich alle Informationen, um MiKTeX wieder in Gang zu bringen.

!   C:\Users\Jakob ~\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\pdflatex.log

! pdflatex: major issue: Bis jetzt haben Sie noch nicht nach MiKTeX-Updates gesucht.

Fehler: LaTeX failed to compile vorlage.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See vorlage.log for more info.
Zusätzlich: Warnmeldung:
In do_once((if (is_R_CMD_check()) stop else warning)("The function xfun::isFALSE() will be deprecated in the future. Please ",  :
  The function xfun::isFALSE() will be deprecated in the future. Please consider using base::isFALSE(x) or identical(x, FALSE) instead.
Ausführung angehalten
```

I reinstalled MikTeX (and also rebooted the system before I trying again), but it didn't work.

I didn't get the problem solved and did not find a solution. So I uninstalled MikTeX and I tried tinytex. I installed it with `install.packages("tinytex")`, but it didn't work either:

```
Fehler: LaTeX failed to compile vorlage.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips.
Zusätzlich: Warnmeldungen:
1: In do_once((if (is_R_CMD_check()) stop else warning)("The function xfun::isFALSE() will be deprecated in the future. Please ",  :
  The function xfun::isFALSE() will be deprecated in the future. Please consider using base::isFALSE(x) or identical(x, FALSE) instead.
2: In system2(..., stdout = if (use_file_stdout()) f1 else FALSE, stderr = f2) :
  '"pdflatex"' not found
Ausführung angehalten
```

I read that maybe `tinytex::install_tinytex()` could work better, but that didn't work for me and i got this error message in the console:

```
Error in system2("tlmgr", args, ...) : '"tlmgr"' not found
In addition: Warning message:
In extract(pkg, exdir = path.expand(target)) :
  error 1 in extracting from zip file
```

I tried an other template, but it doesn't work for me.
However, knitting works for short Markdown documents (without yaml header).